# ImportError: cannot import name 'register_tortoise' from 'tortoise.contrib.pydantic'

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, pylance, tortoise-orm

I hope everyone are safe and fine. I am trying this code to make it work. I have a main.py file and models.py file where I have a Class User created in the models.py file and I am trying to import the User class from models.py file to main.py file. I a using Tortoise ORM for this purpose. I am getting an error "ImportError: cannot import name 'register_tortoise' from 'tortoise.contrib.pydantic'" in the command prompt

```
**main.py**

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from models import User_Pydantic, UserIn_Pydantic, User
from tortoise.contrib.pydantic import register_tortoise, HTTPNotFoundError



app = FastAPI()


register_tortoise(
    app,
    db_url="sqlite://store.db",
    modules={'models':['models']},
    generate_schemas = True,
    add_exception_handlers = True

)

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")



@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def login_page(request :Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request":request})


@app.post("/loginsuccess/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def login_success(request: Request, username: str = Form(...), password: str = Form(...)):

    if username=='michael' and password=='clarke':
        return templates.TemplateResponse("homepage.html", {"request": request, "username":username})
    else:
        status_code:int
        status_code = 500
        return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request":request, "status_code":status_code})
```

```
**models.py**

from tortoise import fields
from tortoise.models import Model
from tortoise.contrib.pydantic import pydantic_model_creator

class User(Model):
    id = fields.CharField(pk=True, max_length=50)
    username = fields.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    password = fields.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)


    class PydanticMeta:
        pass 

User_Pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(User, name="User")
UserIn_Pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(User, name="UserIn", exclude_readonly=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The library's API was changed, and you need to use this one:

```
from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import HTTPNotFoundError, register_tortoise
```

instead for:

```
from tortoise.contrib.pydantic import register_tortoise, HTTPNotFoundError
```